# How to create a new list of integers from a parent list containing integers and string?

Tags: python

```
List=["2","10","15","23","exit"]

# Output required
List_new = [2,10,15,23]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `isnumeric`:

```
[int(item) for item in List if item.isnumeric()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isnumeric`

```
>>> List=["2","10","15","23","exit"]
>>> output = [int(i) for i in List if i.isnumeric()]
>>> print(output)
[2, 10, 15, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.isdigit()`

```
List_given =["2","10","15","23","exit"]
def new_list(List_given):
    List_new = []
    for item in list(List_given):
        if item.isdigit():
            List_new.append(item)
    return List_new
new_list(List_given)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do that:

```
List_new = [int(i) for i in List if i.isnumeric()]
```